# duplicate output fro mysql

Tags: mysql, duplicates, opencart

MySQL query gives duplicate data in query result. Here is how I am trying to avoid it.

Actual query:

```
$product_sql_test2 = $this->db->query("SELECT p.product_id, p.price,    pc.product_id AS product_id
    FROM oc_product p
        INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category pc ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
    WHERE p.price  BETWEEN '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_min_2']."' and '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_max_2']."'
        AND pc.category_id =  '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_id_2']."'
    GROUP BY pc.product_id
    ORDER BY RAND( ) 
    LIMIT 0 , 10");
```

Here is what I do after selection:

```
if(isset($product_sql_test2->row['product_id'])){$this->data['product_spec_2_'.$i.''] = $product_sql_test2->row['product_id'];}
    $i++;
}

$pr_unique2 = array_unique($this->data['product_spec_2_'.$i.'']);
if ($this->data['product_spec_2_'.$i.''] != $pr_unique2[$i]){
    $product_sql_test2 = $this->db->query("SELECT  p.product_id, p.price,    pc.product_id AS product_id
        FROM oc_product p
            LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_category pc ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
        WHERE p.price  BETWEEN '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_min_2']."' and '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_max_2']."'
            AND pc.category_id =  '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_id_2']."'
        GROUP BY pc.product_id
        ORDER BY RAND( ) 
        LIMIT 0 , 10");//$sql_price_minus = $product_info['price'] - ($product_info['price'] * 0.10);
    $this->data['product_spec_2_'.$i.''] = $product_sql_test2->row['product_id'];
    continue;
}
```

How can I prevent duplicate results?

Here is how I edited the code, but got an error that said that query executed more then 30 seconds. What can be done?

```
$product_sql_test2 = $this->db->query("SELECT p.product_id, p.price,    pc.product_id AS product_id
FROM oc_product p
LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_category pc ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
WHERE p.price  BETWEEN '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_min_2']."' and '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_max_2']."'
AND pc.category_id =  '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_id_2']."'
GROUP BY pc.product_id
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 10");                        

if(isset($product_sql_test2->row['product_id'])){$this->data['product_spec_2_'.$i.''] = $product_sql_test2->row['product_id'];}
$data[]=$this->data['product_spec_2_'.$i.''];
$pr_unique = array_unique($data);

$i++;
if ($data != $pr_unique[$i]){
  $product_sql_test2 = $this->db->query("SELECT p.product_id, p.price,    pc.product_id AS product_id
FROM oc_product p
LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_category pc ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
WHERE p.price  BETWEEN '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_min_2']."' and '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_max_2']."'
AND pc.category_id =  '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_id_2']."'
GROUP BY pc.product_id
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 10");                        
    $i=1;
}
if(isset($product_sql_test2->row['product_id'])){$this->data['product_spec_2_'.$i.''] = $product_sql_test2->row['product_id'];}
$i++;
```

Comment: I don't see how you can be getting duplicates when you have `GROUP BY pc.product_id`. There should only ever be one result from each product_id.

Comment: Well I actually don't know either. Please help what can I do?

Comment: group by only does anything useful if you have an aggregate in the SELECT list (e.g. sum, count). At a guess you have products in more than one category. If you show a cut down version of your data showing the problem I think it would be easier to diagnose

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn That's not true for mysql. If you have multiple products with different prices, it just returns one of them. [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Comment: Well I am getting a product ID and then joining selected ID with price in an other table. And after all displaying the result.

Comment: I suggest you create a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) link with some sample data that demonstrates the problem. I've tried reproducing the issue and nothing I did would give me duplicate data from that query.

Comment: The problem is I can't do it since because I am using Opencart.

Comment: @JamesHolderness - while true with MySQL, it does just mean GROUP BY is being used as a nasty equivalent of DISTINCT, but bringing back values from random rows for the non GROUP BY  fields

Comment: Well But I am grouping by ids and that still returns duplicated values. I also Tried DISTINCT but it do nothing except taking extra space in code.

Comment: By the way that what this query returns:

Comment: Toshiba DT01ACA300, HDD SATA3 3.5", 3TB 1108 Western Digital WD2002FAEX, HDD SATA3 3.5", 2TB 1320 Toshiba DT01ACA300, HDD SATA3 3.5", 3TB 1108 Western Digital WD2002FAEX, HDD SATA3 3.5", 2TB 1320

Comment: There is no reason your new code should hang for 30 seconds. I would suspect that some other code is calling that bit of code repeatedly