# mysql query keeps returning duplicated results

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, opencart

I hava a query that returns duplicat results. Here it is:

```
$product_sql_test2 = $this->db->query("SELECT p.product_id, p.price,    pc.product_id AS product_id
FROM oc_product p
INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category pc ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
WHERE p.price  BETWEEN '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_min_2']."' and '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_max_2']."'
AND pc.category_id =  '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_id_2']."'
GROUP BY pc.product_id
ORDER BY RAND( ) 
LIMIT 0 , 10");
```

I have tried to use array_unique function but it  doesn't do anything. What could be done?

P.s. I have asked similar question before, but got no answer the link to it is:
[previous question with full source code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511560/duplicate-output-fro-mysql)

With best regards 
Bogdan

p.p.s. source code now

```
if(isset($product_info['related_kv4nt_id_2'])) 
{
    $i=1;
    $imax = 5;
    while ($i < $imax) 
    {
        $product_sql_test2 = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT p.product_id, p.price,    pc.product_id AS product_id
                                                FROM oc_product p
                                                INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category pc ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
                                                WHERE p.price  BETWEEN '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_min_2']."' and '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_max_2']."'
                                                AND pc.category_id =  '".$product_info['related_kv4nt_id_2']."'
                                                GROUP BY pc.product_id
                                                ORDER BY RAND( ) 
                                                LIMIT 0 , 10");
        if(isset($product_sql_test2->row['product_id']))
        {
            $this->data['product_spec_2_'.$i.''] = $product_sql_test2->row['product_id'];
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [duplicate output fro mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511560/duplicate-output-fro-mysql)

Comment: What do you want the GROUP BY to do? What it will do is bring back one row for each pc.product_id, but if there was more than one row then which matching row from oc_product which is used for the fields returned is undefined. It should not return a full duplicate record. Can you post some sample data and what is being returned and what you would like returned

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `DISTINCT` clause in your select statement http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: Thank you, but it still duplicating.

Comment: That what it is returning:

Comment: Toshiba DT01ACA300, HDD SATA3 3.5", 3TB

1108

Western Digital WD2002FAEX, HDD SATA3 3.5", 2TB

1320 

Toshiba DT01ACA300, HDD SATA3 3.5", 3TB

1108 

Western Digital WD2002FAEX, HDD SATA3 3.5", 2TB

1320

Comment: Toshiba DT01ACA300, HDD SATA3 3.5", 3TB

1108

Seagate ST4000DM000, HDD SATA3 3.5", 4TB

1622 


Seagate ST3000DM001, HDD SATA3 3.5", 3TB

1084 
Western Digital WD2002FAEX, HDD SATA3 3.5", 2TB

1320

Comment: To me that looks like the section of code is being executed twice rather than the SQL returning duplicates

Comment: I have added the source code in my question. Please read it. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You code is looping around and doing exactly the same select 4 times.

Comment: Well I moved the query right above the while loop, but now I am getting only one product 4 times How can I get more then that?